# Webpack still "Cannot find module" after I fixed reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I had an import that was incorrect, like:

```
import * from './housetree.js';
```

Then when building, Webpack expectedly complained with a `Cannot find module './housetree.js'` error. So I fixed the reference to:

```
import * from './treehouse.js';
```

Webpack still complains about the older reference with the same `Cannot find module './housetree.js'`. I've searched my code base for any use of the incorrect form, but found none. It is like Webpack is evaluating an old version of the code from a cache or something like that.

Any advice on solving this?

--Background info about project--

Webpack version is 2.3.3.
Project follows a typical React build process - with an "npm run build" executing Babel, Webpack, Jasmine unit tests, SASS processing.
Source files are ES6 Javascript.

Comment: can you share the project structure and the code in those files

Comment: For confidentiality, I have to fake up analogous code and names of files to put an example. So it's not just copy-and-paste. I'll update with a little more information, and please ask for anything specific you'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
import * from '../{DIR_NAME}/treehouse.js';
```

when **{DIR_NAME}** is the directory name

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem to go away by deleting my node_modules directory and reinstalling all the node packages. I did not troubleshoot deeply to find the exact cause of the problem. But I can say that one of the build tools kept state of some kind under the project's node_modules.

This is probably not a terrific question since it relies a lot on the specifics of my build process that I can't easily describe. I'm self-answering it out of doubts that others will be able to provide an applicable answer without a lot more detail. And since the problem is solved on my end, I don't have motivation to explore it further.